# C++ If statement skipped

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics

I'm implementing collision resolution with two AABB's but it seems "if(*yDepth > 0)" is being completely skipped by the compiler. When i apply a breakpoint to the statement within visual studio it replies "this breakpoint will not currently be hit. Is it an issue with pointers? I have tried moving the contents of the statement, changing conditions, but it seems to always skip the if statement in question.

```
Vector2* normal = new Vector2();
Vector2* vFrom1to2 = new Vector2();
*vFrom1to2 = Vector2(b->getX() - a->getX(), b->getY() - a->getY());
float* xDepth = new float();
*xDepth = (a->getWidth()) + (b->getWidth()) - abs(vFrom1to2->x);
float* yDepth = new float();


if (*xDepth > 0) {

    *yDepth = (a->getHeight()) + (b->getHeight()) - abs(vFrom1to2->y);
    std::cout << "break";
    if (*yDepth > 0) { //this statement is skipped completely. yDepth is greater than 0 on testing.

        if (xDepth < yDepth) {
            if (vFrom1to2->x < 0) {
                normal->x == -1;
                normal->y == 0;
            }
            else {
                normal->x == 1;
                normal->y == 0;
            }

        }
        else {
            if (vFrom1to2->y < 0) {
                normal->x == 0;
                normal->y == -1;
            }
            else {
                normal->x == 0;
                normal->y == 1;
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: why all the `new`s? `new` is old news in C++

Comment: That's one sub-optimal use of storage, why allocation `float` in dynamic memory? Javascript much?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie sub-optimal use of storage is the last problem. How about memory leaks?

Comment: Is this a release or debug build?

Comment: @bolov That's expected if I saw whole block. So far I see something which MAY lead to leak and semantically shoyld have been an automatic storage. The code is incomplete. Impossuble to say why  check is skipped or fails, the a and b variables are not here.

Comment: It's definitely not the C++ issue. Post complete code or at least.the context...

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie regardless of what is missing or not. An owning raw pointer can always memory leak. Because of a very little known and obscure C++ feature: exceptions :)

Comment: and even smart ones can leak if used framework messes with implementation of those.

Comment: Input are pointers of two square objects. Other than that the whole code is currently there.

Comment: @JackAidley release i believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In release mode - or more precisely, when optimisation is on - the compiler can re-order, re-arrange, combine or even remove lines of code. This means that there is no longer a one to one correspondence between the lines of code you wrote and the machine code that is actually produced. This can mean that certain lines of code can no longer have breakpoints assigned to them and the debugger may skip around when stepping through your code.

Usually, it is better to debug in debug mode for this reason. If this is not possible, set a breakpoint near the line you are interested in and step through the code from there rather than on the exact line you are interested in.

(Note to readers: the asker clarified in a comment that they are experiencing this problem in release mode)

Comment: Sadly i do not have access to debug mode. I have attempted to break before but it acts as if the line is not even there. Within the same function, I've attempted to remove all code except a simple nested if statement, both with the condition if(1>0). The second if statement is always skipped. Incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @Cotchsloth: you could try introducing something into the if statement that has a side-effect (i.e. print the values to std::cout or similar). But if the values are as you suggest, the most likely thing is that the debugger is misleading you about what is happening. This is very common in release builds.

Comment: @Cotchsloth: the other possibility is that the `normal` variable is getting removed by a dead-stripper. Do you use the value afterwards?

Comment: yes i'm using the normal afterwards. I'll test further with some out statements. Cheers

Comment: Strangely if i place cout statements after each if statement the if statements get called. but the assignment of values for the normal.x and .y do not. Maybe something to do with normal?

Comment: Oh dear. it seems that i was using compare operators not assignment so the statements were being skipped. Stupid mistake, Cheers for your time

Comment: @Cotchsloth: You're welcome. Honestly, I'm embarrassed that I didn't spot that.